# Why does pgf only draw one path for me?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my more or less minimal example where I draw a ‘document’ shape with a little folded corner. Values are hardcoded to decrease the size of the example.

My problem is that in `beforebackgroundpath`, I clearly give commands to draw one thick red stroke, then move a bit lower and draw another, thinner black one. However, only the thick red line is drawn.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \backgroundpath{
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % main shape
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
        \advance\pgf@xc by-10pt
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        % fold
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \beforebackgroundpath{
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % lines
        \advance\pgf@xa by+5pt
        \advance\pgf@xb by-5pt
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{(\pgf@yb-\pgf@ya)/8}
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@ya by-10pt
        \pgf@xc=.3\pgf@xb
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[document,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=5cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgf@xb` gets overwritten by `\pgfusepath{stroke}`, so you draw a line of length 0pt. You need to set `\pgf@xb` afterwards, for example

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \backgroundpath{
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % main shape
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
        \advance\pgf@xc by-10pt
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        % fold
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
    }
    \beforebackgroundpath{
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % lines
        \advance\pgf@xa by+5pt
        \advance\pgf@xb by-5pt
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{(\pgf@yb-\pgf@ya)/8}%
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@ya by-10pt
        \pgf@xc=.3\pgf@xb
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{red}%
        \pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}%
        \typeout{before pgfusepath: xb=\the\pgf@xb}%
        \pgfusepath{stroke}%
        \typeout{after pgfusepath: xb=\the\pgf@xb}%
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}%
        \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
        \pgf@xb=2\pgf@xc
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
        \pgfusepath{stroke}%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[document,draw,text width=3cm,minimum height=5cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to draw such a simple picture? Or do I miss something?

Comment: @KeksDose Of course there is a simpler way to draw such a picture but question concerns a node shape, which has a lot of additional features.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed fixes my problem. I should have noticed this in the PGF manual:  ‘**Attention:** PGF uses these registers to perform path operations. For reasons of efficiency, path commands do not always guard them.’

Comment: Are there better ‘best practices’ to declare shapes other than the way I present in my question, ie setting `\pgf@{x,y}{a,b,c}` and drawing paths between points with coordinates constructed from these values? I sometimes also use `\@tempdim{a,b}` when I run out of registers. Is this the preferred way? I find it often very hard to follow which register currently contains what and which can be reused without realizing one will need it again later.

Comment: @bp99 I do not know what the recommended way is. However, if you look at the pgf libraries of shapes, you can see that sometimes extra local macros are defined, e.g. in `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex` one has `\xpathradius` and `\ypathradius`. That is, in order to just "remember" a length you do not need necessarily a length register, but can also use a local macro. However, I am not claiming that this is the "better" or "preferred" way.